# Hide source code of Electron alteast 1 file.. Possible?

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, cefsharp

Hey so i started using Electron becouse of HTML/CSS/JS possibilites.

I have expirience mostly with PHP and some little with JS.

Was searching how to hide files of Electron (becouse .asar file can be unpacked) and its just stupid to put my MySQL server info in .js file and let users see that info..

Is there any way to hide atleast 1 .js file where i would put all necessery stuff like mysql connection and mysql managing?

I googled a lot about that some people say that Node.JS can to that but i cant find anywhere how to exacly do it?

Tried to switch to CEFSharp but cant realise how to interact between C# and Webpage (used webserver for template and php stuff but like how to tell C# that variable of A is A and use that C# variable for something)..

Hope somebody will help me, maybe its dumb question for some expirienced developers but i mostly work in PHP and i wanna learn new stuff..

Thanks!

Comment: Electron is made for stand-alone apps. It's like willing to hide your credentials in any app that will be running client-side. You don't want to do that. Solution is probably to have an API server to make the queries to your database.

Answer (score 1):

Long story in short - no. In deep down, *any code* you ship in client to users should be considered to be revealed, just matter of how hard will it be. Instead of shipping important credential and obfuscate to not able to read it, application should be designed to be safe even if user reads whole code in client.

Comment: just fyi, you mentioned about using C# - disassemling plain C# code is as easy as reading plain text file.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not really any sort of expert on Electron.  I'll assume that you will either create a login or a config file.  In the first case you can use the database to determine if access is allowed.  If you don't want to setup a login script then you can use a config.json file that is not part of the build file.  There are a few node packages you can use -  I believe one is "electron-storage" to help with the access to the database.  Hope this helps.
Johnf